# How to make HttpResponse.Flush() async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, flush

How to implement an asynchrone call to the HttpResponse.Flush() method using .net 4.0 & VS2013 ?

I tried delegate:

```
var caller = new AsyncFlush(context.Response.Flush);
var result1 = caller.BeginInvoke(null, null);
caller.EndInvoke(result1);
```

then task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Response.Flush()).Start();
```

and finally thread:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => context.Response.Flush()).Start();
```

But each case seem freeze my internet explorer when flushing larges files (1GB+). Any idea?

Regards.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` maybe?

Comment: Can you be more specific about in where are you using this code? Asp.net   Forms/MVC/WebApi/Handlers etc. So that it can be answered precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach for creating async wrapper is fine. But here are few things you should know.

Response.Flush() forces the complete buffer to send to the client. So try to avoid sending a complete 1 Gig+ data on the client at once. This might engage the client processing that huge buffer and might endup with hangs.

Rather than sending the huge buffer once to the client try sending the stream into chunks and use flush for each chunk, so that client doesn't hang during processing your request.

See [this KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812406) for writing a huge file in chunks to the response using Response.Flush multiple times.

Comment: Given that this answer has been accepted I want to add the following: All assumptions made here about the client are false. The client cannot even detect the chunk size used to write data. See my answer for a more correct picture. I'm not even sure what that KB article talks about. It is nonsense and does not even say what problem it solves. It leaves out the name of the client. It's for .NET 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

Whether your flush the response or not does not matter. It also does not matter what chunk size you use when writing to the response object. Client and server communicate over the TCP protocol which does not preserve or communicate chunk sizes in any way. The client is never impacted by the way the server wrote. The client can't even tell the difference if it wanted to. It's an implementation detail of the server.

The reason why your browser "freezes" is unknown but it is not the way you flush data. Browsers have no trouble downloading arbitrarily sized files.

Note, that all three of the code samples you posted are either slightly harmful and pointless or do not work at all. You need to throw this away. Look elsewhere for finding the reason for the freeze.